# filter a csv file on a ftp server

Tags: php, csv, ftp

I need to open a csv file on a remote ftp server, filter the data and then save the result in a new file on the same ftp server.

I wonder if this is possible without downloading the file. I probably need to create a stream but don't know how.

The filter is not very difficult. I just need to filter the records for a specific date and also strip out a few columns.

Any ideas?

Thanks
Aleks

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have to download it. But using cURL it's straightforward.

Download :

```
curl ftp://myftpsite.com/path/to/csv/your_file.csv --user myname:mypassword -o your_file.csv
```

Upload :

```
curl -T your_file.csv ftp://myftpsite.com/path/to/csv/ --user myname:mypassword
```

Depending on what you need to do (which seems quite simple), you probably don't even need php to do that.
A simple bash script could have it done in very few lines of code.

Comment: Good idea. But out of curiosity I'd really like to solve it in PHP. In the meantime I've already solved the download and filter for date problem. Now I only need to strip out the unwanted columns.